# Solve a complex sum that does not seem to be a series

Tags: probability, summation

What is the simplest way to find `n` in the equation

$$\sum_{i=8}^n {n \choose i} 0.3^i 0.7^{n-i} < 0.02$$

I can solve this programmatically `n=16`, or in a simpler for but I'm stuck here.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n 0.3^i 0.7^{n-i} - \sum_{i=0}^8 0.3^i 0.7^{n-i}\\=(0.3+0.7)^n - (0.3+0.7)^7$$ was my initial idea but it does not seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

The largest term in your series is the first and the common ratio is $\frac{3}{7}$ so even the sum to infinity of the series is less than $0.02$.

Comment: In the case that we have $nCi \cdot 0.3^i 0.7^{n-i}$ would it change? I tried with that inside the sum but it still seems not solvable. Yet if I just compute this for various `n`s I end up with one that satisfies it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no binomial coefficients and the binomial theorem does not apply.

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=8}^n0.3^i0.7^{n-i}=\frac{0.3^80.7^{n-8}[1-(\frac{0.3}{0.7})^{n-7}]}{1-\frac{0.3}{0.7}}$

Comment: I think Dolan is right so I had to edit the question, I think I made it solvable this time.

Answer (score 0):

The same answer as CY Aries but with explanations:

Basically it is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) and you can use the formula
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} r^i=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$
for $r = \frac37\ne1$.

So
$$
\sum_{i=8}^n 0.3^i0.7^{n-i}
 = \sum_{i=0}^{n-8}0.3^{i+8}0.7^{n-(i+8)}
 = 0.3^80.7^{n-8}\sum_{i=0}^{n-8}\left(\frac37\right)^i
 = 0.3^80.7^{n-8}\left(\frac{1-\left(\frac37\right)^{n-7}}{1-\frac37}\right)
$$